# Quiet volume on headphone jack on ASUS Eee 1005HA

Tags: windows-7, audio, eee-pc

I have an ASUS Eee 1005HA running Windows 7 Starter.  The volume output of the headphone jack is extremely low.  Otherwise, the speakers work fine.

I downloaded and installed the most recent audio drivers (V6.0.1.5948) from ASUS but that did not resolve the issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: I know that in 7 regular you have the ability to change the sound levels of different devices. Have you checked whether the volume of the headphone output (if you click the icon and choose playback devices it should show which you have)

Comment: Yes, it looks like I can modify the device volume.  However, it is set to 100.

Comment: Does that happen to all programs?

Comment: Yes, it is very quiet in all programs I have attempted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with an ASUS laptop on Windows 7 too.

I just got myself a cheap USB soundcard [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) or [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027EMHM6):
[image]

Now I usually set Windows' volume to 50% - 70% only, (with my headphones, it gets too loud when I go higher), I also get better quality sound with it than my laptop's sound card. You could put an external speaker thru the USB soundcard and get better quality sounds too.